# Finding the bounds of a single pixel in a raster in Python

Tags: python, raster, shapely, rasterio

I have a satellite image and a group of polygons scattered around the image. The polygons are small and cover a single-pixel most of the time; I'm trying to create a new raster where each pixel value represents how many polygons are inside that specific pixel of the satellite image.

I thought about creating a new polygon with coordinates that represent the bounds of pixels and then use a library such as shapely to determine whether the polygons overlap or not.

The only issue is that I didn't manage to find a way on how to calculate an individual pixel's bounds.

Comment: Rasterio's `rasterio.features.rasterize` with `all_touched=True` and `merge_alg=MergeAlg.add` may help you.
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.rasterize